# Memory leak for custom tensorflow training using @tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, custom-training

I am trying to write my own training loop for `TF2/Keras`, following the official Keras walkthrough. The vanilla version works like a charm, but when I try to add the `@tf.function` decorator to my training step, some memory leak grabs all my memory and I lose control of my machine, does anyone know what is going on?.

The important parts of the code look like this:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = siamese_network(x, training=True)
        loss_value = loss_fn(y, logits)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, siamese_network.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, siamese_network.trainable_weights))
    train_acc_metric.update_state(y, logits)
    return loss_value

@tf.function
def test_step(x, y):
    val_logits = siamese_network(x, training=False)
    val_acc_metric.update_state(y, val_logits)
    val_prec_metric.update_state(y_batch_val, val_logits)
    val_rec_metric.update_state(y_batch_val, val_logits)


for epoch in range(epochs):
        step_time = 0
        epoch_time = time.time()
        print("Start of {} epoch".format(epoch))
        for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_ds):
            if step > steps_epoch:
                break
           
            loss_value = train_step(x_batch_train, y_batch_train)
        train_acc = train_acc_metric.result()
        train_acc_metric.reset_states()
        
        for val_step,(x_batch_val, y_batch_val) in enumerate(test_ds):
            if val_step>validation_steps:
                break
            test_step(x_batch_val, y_batch_val)
         
        val_acc = val_acc_metric.result()
        val_prec = val_prec_metric.result()
        val_rec = val_rec_metric.result()

        val_acc_metric.reset_states()
        val_prec_metric.reset_states()
        val_rec_metric.reset_states()
```

If I comment on the `@tf.function` lines, the memory leak doesn't occur, but the step time is 3 times slower. My guess is that somehow the graph is bean created again within each epoch or something like that, but I have no idea how to solve it.

This is the tutorial I am following: https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/

Comment: are you using GPU? if no, change it to GPU. also, try to reduce batch size.

Comment: How are your `train_ds` and `test_ds` created? When you enumerate over them do you get tensors or some other type?

Answer (score 3):

#### tl;dr;

TensorFlow may be generating a new graph for each unique set of argument values passed into the decorated functions. Make sure you are passing consistently-shaped `Tensor` objects to `test_step` and `train_step` instead of python objects.

#### Details

This is a stab in the dark. While I've never tried `@tf.function`, I did find the following warnings in [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function):

> tf.function also treats any pure Python value as opaque objects, and builds a separate graph for each set of Python arguments that it encounters.

and

> Caution: Passing python scalars or lists as arguments to tf.function will always build a new graph. To avoid this, pass numeric arguments as Tensors whenever possible

Finally:

> A Function determines whether to reuse a traced ConcreteFunction by computing a cache key from an input's args and kwargs. A cache key is a key that identifies a ConcreteFunction based on the input args and kwargs of the Function call, according to the following rules (which may change):
>
> - The key generated for a tf.Tensor is its shape and dtype.
> - The key generated for a tf.Variable is a unique variable id.
> - The key generated for a Python primitive (like int, float, str) is its value.
> - The key generated for nested dicts, lists, tuples, namedtuples, and attrs is the flattened tuple of leaf-keys (see nest.flatten). (As a result of this flattening, calling a concrete function with a different nesting structure than the one used during tracing will result in a TypeError).
> - For all other Python types the key is unique to the object. This way a function or method is traced independently for each instance it is called with.

What I get from all this is that if you don't pass in a consistently-sized Tensor object to your `@tf.function`-ified function (perhaps you use Python collections or primitives instead), it is likely that you are creating a new graph version of your function with every distinct argument value you pass in. I'm guessing this could create the memory explosion behavior you're seeing. I can't tell how your `test_ds` and `train_ds` objects are being created, but you might want to make sure that they are created such that `enumerate(blah_ds)` returns tensors like in the tutorial, or at least convert the values to tensors before passing to your `test_step` and `train_step` functions.

Comment: Hi!
The network I am training is a Siamese one, therefore I got two inputs. Originally, they were represented as a dictionary, a python object indeed. I tried to convert them to a Tensor with `x_prueba = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_prueba)` and used this new variable as input to the train_step function, but still, the memory usage is growing and growing. They are of the eagerTensor type, dont know if that is relevant though.

Comment: I am using TF 1.15, but when I run `tf.convert_to_tensor(my_dict)` I get `TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'dict'> to Tensor.`. Maybe it it's a version difference. Are you sure you are passing in a tensor and not a dictionary of tensors?

Comment: I mean passing in a tensor and not a dictionary of tensors to your `tf.function`-decorated functions...

Comment: I had to do some preprocessing. I do not convert directly the dictionary to a tensor: I append the two entries of the dictionary into a list, and that list is converted to a tensor with dimensions [2,35,280,4], where that "2" is the extra dimension added. This tensor is the x input to the train_step function

Im using TF 2.4, just in case

Comment: In that case it sounds like my guess was just wrong.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Comment: I had the same issue when training GAN in Colab with Tesla V100 GPU. It worked well I decorated the functions with @tf.function. But after function decoration, I got resource exhausted error. I solved it by reducing the batch size to half.